# When I'm using map local it maps several requests

Tags: replace, http-proxy, charles-proxy

My path is `/api/query` without any Query Parameters, but Charles maps all requests that have path `/api/query`.

In other words:

Charles maps `/api/query?some=1`, `/api/query?another=1` and `/api/query` requests, but I need just `/api/query`. I need to be mapped clear request without query parameters.

version: 3.12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have figured out but there is an alternative tool that works the same as Charles named [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/). Basically, just **right click** your URL --> select **Tools** --> **Map Local**

1. If you check "Include all subpaths of this domain" --> Proxyman will map all requests including subpaths such as `/api/query?some=1`, `/api/query?another=1` and `/api/query`

[image]

2. If you uncheck the box --> Proxyman will map `/api/query` only

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version on their website. You can download it from https://proxyman.io/